# CLONE_VM flag makes itimer inaccurate?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, system-calls

Recently I come across a problem about sharing memory with multiprocess. Consider the code below, the main purpose is to let child process alarmed by the itimer's signal handler, do some output. But what confuses me is that when I set the CLONE_VM flag in clone() function, the itimer may go wrong, and the output text will stuff your console.

**What I expect is : print "---Alarm!\n---ChildThread is awaked.\n---foo=10" every second.**

**The actual situation is : repeat printing the text above very fast.**

I'd like to know how to spawn a child PROCESS and let it share its parent's memory in the meanwhile. Thanks a lot.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

static volatile int foo = 100;

int pidChild;

void AlarmThread(int sig)
{
    printf("---Alarm!\n");
    kill(pidChild, SIGCONT);
}

int ChildThread(void *arg)
{
    raise(SIGSTOP);
    while(1)
    {
        printf("---ChildThread is awaked.\n");
        printf("---foo=%d\n", foo);     // If CLONE_VM is set, this variable may be changed by main thread.
        raise(SIGSTOP);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *stack = malloc(4000) + 4000;
    struct itimerval itimer;
    signal(SIGALRM, AlarmThread);
    pidChild = clone(ChildThread, stack, CLONE_VM | CLONE_SIGHAND, NULL);
    itimer.it_interval.tv_sec = 1;
    itimer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;
    itimer.it_value = itimer.it_interval;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &itimer, NULL);   // Set up a 1 tick-per-sec timer.
    foo = 10;   // Test if the child thread shares the main thread's memory.
    while(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you deliberately ignoring the existence of `fork()` and `pthread_create()` for a specific reason?

Comment: Because I want to spawn a kill()-able PROCESS, so I can't use pthread lib. fork() may be a choice, but invoking a call-back function in new process using it seems to be more complicated. Since clone() is more customizable, so I decide to use it initially.

Comment: I would put serious money against the claim that `clone` is *easier* than `fork`...

Comment: I just want to spawn a process that can: 1.kill()-able  2.run with the other processes together  3.share main process' memory  4.ONLY invoke a specific call-back function.  Any good ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would really caution you *against* doing this. Sharing memory does not mean only application memory, but also library memory (the standard library and any third-party libraries you may use), and they may not be prepared for having other processes clobber their internal data structures, especially when they believe themselves to be running single-threaded.

If you just want a process in order to have a killable PID for a thread as part of the publicly visible interface of your application, why not make the actual code run in a thread, and spawn a useless child process that does nothing but `for(;;)pause();`? Then, have the thread respond to the death of this child process by exiting.

Answer (score 0):

> But what confuses me is that when I set the CLONE_VM flag in clone()
>   function, the itimer may go wrong, and the output text will stuff your
>   console.

What does "may go wrong" mean? What happened? What did you expect? You need to be clear when asking questions.

CLONE_VM has almost nothing to do with itimer. The fact that you are using advanced syscalls like this without even being able to formulate what you are trying to do and why leads me to believe this is a school assignment.